# How to run reactJS in vscode.dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I want to run my react app on <vscode.dev> which is basically visual studio code but on the web browser like google chrome. But I wasn't able to it since no terminal is available there (on web browser).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that, try installing VS Code locally

Comment: You could probably connect vscode.dev to a github repo & set up some gh actions to build & publish to gh-pages if local isn't an option at all.

Comment: Terminals are not available in the web editor

Comment: @CollinD can you kindly explain it a bit.
Thanks!

Comment: Not really space to explain the entire process in a stackoverflow comment, but there's plenty of guides on how to set up GH-pages. https://dev.to/achukka/deploy-react-app-using-github-actions-157d just a random one I found via googling, there are tons.